# How to start from the last line with tail?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, tail

I have a huge log file. I need to find something and print last line. Like this:

```
tail -n +1 "$log" | awk '$9 ~ "'$something'" {print $0}' | tail -n1
```

But when I execute this command, `tail` starts from 1st line and reads all the lines. And running few mins.

How can I start to read from the last line and stop when I find something? So maybe I don't need to read all lines and running just few secs. Because I need just last line about `$something`.

Comment: You need the last line that contains a certain word? if so you should combine `grep` and `tail`.

Comment: Yes, I need to print just last line about $something. But without reading all lines.

Comment: Note the difference between `tail -n+X` (print from line X) and `tail -X` / `tail -nX` (tail X last lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note you are saying `tail -n +1 "$log"`, which is interpreted by `tail` as: start reading from line `1`. So you are in fact doing `cat "$log"`.

You probably want to say `tail -n 1 "$log"` (without the `+` before `1`) to get the last `n` lines.

Also, if you want to get the last match of `$something`, you may want to use `tac`. This prints a file backwards: first the last line, then the penultimate... and finally the first one.

So if you do

```
tac "$log" | grep -m1 "$something"
```

this will print the last match of `$something` and then exit, because `-mX` prints the first `X` matches.

Or of course you can use `awk` as well:

```
tac "$log" | awk -v pattern="$something" '$9 ~ pattern {print; exit}'
```

Note the usage of `-v` to give to awk the variable. This way you avoid a confusing mixure of single and double quotes in your code.

Comment: Thank you, it's work for me. Can I use more than 1 pattern? Like if ~ something and something2, print.

Comment: @iyonizer sure, you can say for example: `awk -v pattern="$something" '$9 ~ pattern && $7==7 {print; exit}'`. Note the `&&` to introduce the other condition if you want both to be accomplished. If it is an OR, then use `||`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `tail`, use `tac`. It will reverse the file and you can exit when you first grep something:

```
tac "$log" | awk '$9 ~ "'$something'" {print $0;exit}'
```

Comment: Don't use the values of shell variables as part of the syntax of your awk script or you can have all sorts of horrible consequences depending on the valeu of that shell variable. Use `-v` to init an awk variable with the value of the shell variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

`tac $FILE | grep $SOMETHING -m 1`

`tac`: the reverse of `cat` :-)

`grep -m`: search and stop on first occurrence

Answer (score 1):

`tail -1000` takes only the last 1000 lines from your file.
You could grep that part, but you wouldn't know if the thing you grep for occurred in the earlier lines. There's no way to grep "backwards".